# Conditionally sum up the values of a column to a defined value

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have a table like this:

```
id | name | amount (in $)
--------------
1  |  A   | 10
1  |  A   | 5 
1  |  A   | 20
1  |  A   | 20
1  |  A   | 40
1  |  A   | 30
2  |  B   | 25
2  |  B   | 20
2  |  B   | 30
2  |  B   | 30
```

How do I sum the amount column of each Id above $5 so that when the sum reaches a certain value, say $50, it performs another sum for that id in the next row?

So, from the table above, we'll have:

```
id | name | amount (in $)
--------------
1  |  A   | 5 --skips the amount that is not above $5
1  |  A   | 50 --the next three rows sum up to $50
1  |  A   | 70 --the value of the next row is not up to $50, so it sums the next line. Summation is more than $50, but no problem
2  |  B   | 75
2  |  B   | 30
```

Comment: oh hi, I had to use C# for that. I was not going to continue the conversation because the question was closed. I'm sorry I didn't give feedback to your answer. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the simplest solution, but it works.

Your sample data is fundamentally flawed, because you need a column to order the rows by to accomplish what you want. I have have assumed you have such a column by adding an identify column to the sample data.

Points to help understanding:

1. Treat the rows of 5 or less separately; so identify the row so we can display it later, and filter it out from the running totals.
2. Calculate a running total across an id ignoring amounts which are too small.
3. With this running total work out when the specified threshold is crossed (by dividing by the threshold)
4. Flag to keep every row where the threshold value changes i.e. its been crossed once, twice, three times etc.
5. For each row kept, subtract the previous value to give the difference.

```
declare @MyTable table (id int, [name] char(1), amount money, uniqueid int identity (1,1));

insert into @MyTable (id, [name], amount)
values
(1,'A',10),
(1,'A',5),
(1,'A',20),
(1,'A',20),
(1,'A',40),
(1,'A',30),
(2,'B',25),
(2,'B',20),
(2,'B',30),
(2,'B',30);

declare @LowerAmount money = 5, @CutoffAmount money = 50;

with cte1 as (
    select *
        , sum(case when amount > @LowerAmount then amount else 0 end) over (partition by id order by uniqueid asc) RunningTotal
        , round(sum(case when amount > @LowerAmount then amount else 0 end) over (partition by id order by uniqueid asc) / @CutoffAmount, 0, 1) CutoffTest
        , case when amount <= @LowerAmount then 1 else 0 end TooSmall
    from @MyTable
), cte2 as (
    select *
        , case when CutoffTest <> lag(CutoffTest, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by uniqueid asc) then RunningTotal else null end RowToKeep
    from cte1
)
select id, [name]
    , case when TooSmall = 1 then amount else RowToKeep-coalesce(lag(RowToKeep,1,0) over (partition by id order by uniqueid asc),0) end amount
from cte2
where TooSmall = 1 or RowToKeep is not null
order by uniqueid asc;
```

Returns as requested:

| id | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5.00 |
| 1 | A | 50.00 |
| 1 | A | 70.00 |
| 2 | B | 75.00 |
| 2 | B | 30.00 |

Note: Providing DDL+DML (as I have shown here) makes it much easier to answer.